# Can an exterior javascript make ajax calls to fetch session data?

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain, session-cookies

Imagine a scenario where you own mysite.com, and it loads javascript from an exterior domain such as adsprovider.com/ads.js.

Can adsprovider.com's javascript then perform an ajax call to mysite.com and attempt to retrieve the user's session data? If so, how can you protect your users against it?

Answer (score 0):

> Can adsprovider.com's javascript then perform an ajax call to mysite.com

Yes. The origin is defined by the URL of the HTML document the script is loaded into, not by the URL the script itself is loaded from.

> retrieve the user's session data

Only if the session data is exposed through HTTP. Stuff you never give to the client is safe (but there is probably going to be quite a lot of session data that should be kept private between your server and the user).

Note that the script can read `document.cookies` and steal the session token too (unless the session token is sent with the *httponly* flag on).

> If so, how can you protect your users against it?

Sandbox the adverts in iframes hosted on different origins.

Answer (score -1):

Fortunatly, an Ajax call for your session data can't be directly request from external server.

You can load javascript from a CDN external source of course, but the script run from your own domain, and access to your server is not possible from outside.
Otherwise there would be a lot of security problem.

Also keep in mind that javascript is client side.

You can check *Same-origin policy* and *CORS* for more info on this topic.

Comment: "the script run from your own domain, and access to your server is not possible from outside" - the point is that since the script runs from your own domain, it **isn't** "from outside"

Comment: Nope. Javascript doesn't have access to your server with ajax from outside, but thx for that...